# why i trying to update the data, but it show me the error on the line "$result=mysqli_query($connection,$query);"

Tags: php, mariadb, sql-update

I have a problem on this, I can't find where is the problem in my code, anyone help me, pls.

```
<?php

if($_POST['submit']) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];

    $query = "UPDATE users SET ";
    $query .="username = '$username' ";
    $query .="password = '$password' ";
    $query .="WHERE id = $id";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    if(!$result) {

        die ('QUERY FAILED' . mysqli_error($connection));

    }

}

?>
```

I need to update the new data into MySQL, but it show me the error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'password='av' WHERE id='

Answer (score 0):

Missing ',' in your query.

```
<?php

if($_POST['submit']) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];

    $query = "UPDATE users SET ";
    $query .= "username = '$username', "; // missing ','
    $query .= "password = '$password' ";
    $query .= "WHERE id = $id";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    if(!$result) {

        die ('QUERY FAILED' . mysqli_error($connection));

    }

}

?>
```

The Update query should be :

`UPDATE users SET username = 'username', password = 'password' where id = 1`

Comment: now i solved my problem by ur suggest, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

As correctly pointed out by Majharul, the error is caused by the missing comma (`,`) between the columns listed in your `SET` clause. The error is almost always immediately preceding the part of the query returned in the error: `password='av' WHERE id=`.

More importantly, you should never store passwords in plain text, nor should you be simply concatenating strings and/or interpolating variables directly into your SQL. This is a very obvious [SQL Injection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) vulnerability and [easy to exploit](https://bobby-tables.com/). You should be using [parameterized prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to pass your variables into your query.

This is a simplistic example (validation of user input should be added) of how you might improve your code:

```
<?php

if($_POST['submit']) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $id = $_POST['id'];

    /* Prepare your UPDATE statement */
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, 'UPDATE users SET username = ?, password = ? WHERE id = ?');

    /* Bind variables to parameters */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssi', $username, $password, $id);

    /* Execute the statement */
    $result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    if(!$result) {

        die ('QUERY FAILED' . mysqli_error($connection));

    }

}
```

Please read [PHP docs for password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash) for more detailed explanation.

Comment: i solved my problem, thank you so much. and thank your for ur remind, . i m a beginner on coding, still learning, thx for the remind!